# Allow One UIButton to be selected in an array and deselect other

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, selected, selectedvalue

The app loads from API product options like color and size for ecommerce app. Now, I am a little stuck in the code.

If one button is selected let us say its color, the other button should be deselected because you can only have one color at a time. Please, take a look at the code below. The code below is the target action when the button is tapped.

```
func imgSelected(_ sender: RadioButton) {
    guard let currentButton = sender as? UIButton else { return }

    if ((currentButton.isSelected) != nil){
        currentButton.isSelected = true
        var dict = JSON(self.catalogProductViewModel.getOption[(sender.superview?.tag)!]);
        let productOptionArray : JSON = JSON(dict["product_option_value"].arrayObject!)
        imageId[(sender.superview?.tag)!] = productOptionArray[sender.tag]["product_option_value_id"].stringValue
        currentButton.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        currentButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        print("Button Not Clicked \((sender as? RadioButton)?.tag)")
    } else {
        currentButton.layer.borderWidth = 0
        currentButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        print("Button Removed \((sender as? RadioButton)?.tag)")
    }
}
```

Yet I can see all options are selectable I tried all possible examples here in the forum non has worked with me. Another Issue I'm facing when casting the product option to the cart it's return the option title and not the selected value for example it's casting to the "Color" instead of "Red".

```
        else if dict["type"].stringValue == "image" {
            if dict["required"].intValue == 1{
                if imageId[i] == ""{
                    isValid = 1;
                    errorMessage = errorMessage+dict["name"].stringValue

                    print("Error Message", errorMessage)
                }else{
                    optionDictionary[dict["product_option_id"].stringValue] = imageId[i] as AnyObject
                    print("Else is Valid 0", optionDictionary[dict["product_option_id"].stringValue] )
                }

            }else{
                optionDictionary[dict["product_option_id"].stringValue] = imageId[i] as AnyObject
                print("Stand Alone", optionDictionary[dict["product_option_id"].stringValue])
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For radio buttons like effect you could do something like following

```
   //This is the implementation of my custom button
class RadioButton: UIButton {
   override var isSelected: Bool {
       didSet {
           refresh()
       }
   }

   private func refresh() {
       //Here We will do when button state changed to selected (maybe radion image selected/ unselected)
       if isSelected {
           //do the selection
           layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
       } else {
           //clear the selection
           layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
       }
   }
}



class MyViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet var radioButtons: [RadioButton]!


    //let say when buttons is clicked we get the call to this function'
    @IBAction private func radioButtonTapped(_ sender: RadioButton) {

        //first clear the buttons selected state
        clearAllSelection()

        //now select the one that triggered this function
        sender.isSelected = true
  }

  //clears selected state for all buttons
  private func clearAllSelection() {
      radioButtons.forEach {
         $0.isSelected = false
      }
  }

}
```

Okay so finally I got the time to look into the RadioButton Library and I think you may have forgot to group the button so that they all belong to same group and thus only one will be selected from that group. I've created a small sample using the Library `createButtonMethod`. Please check and let me know If that is what you were after.

```
func createButtons() {

    let xpos: CGFloat = 50
    var ypos: CGFloat = 100

    for i in 1...3 {

        //create the button with frame
        let frame = CGRect(x: xpos, y: ypos, width: 60, height: 50) //frame for the button
        let radioButton = RadioButton(frame: frame)
        radioButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        //append that button
        buttonArray.append(radioButton)

        //increase the ypos
        ypos += 65

        //set the tag
        radioButton.tag = i

        //add the target
        radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(radioButtonSelected(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        //set the selected and unselected state image of radio button
        radioButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checked"), for: .selected)
        radioButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "unchecked"), for: .normal)

        //finally add that button to the view
        view.addSubview(radioButton)

    }

    //set the group
    buttonArray.first!.groupButtons = buttonArray

    //set first one slected
    buttonArray.first!.isSelected = true


    debugPrint(buttonArray)
}




@objc func radioButtonSelected(_ sender: RadioButton) {
    debugPrint("TAG : \(sender.tag)")
}
```

Here `buttonArray` is variable  `var buttonArray = [RadioButton]()`

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm using RadioButton library created by **Created by Sergey Nikitenko on 3/5/13.** although I'm using Swift3 however this library is ObjC based and the isSelected is defined as following `-(RadioButton*) selectedButton
{
 if([self isSelected]) {
  return self;
 } else {
  for(NSValue* v in _sharedLinks) {
   RadioButton* rb = [v nonretainedObjectValue];
   if([rb isSelected]) {
    return rb;
   }
  }
 }
 return nil;
}`

Comment: I don't know about the library but I've updated my code. I placed some buttons on storyboard and created collection (those button have class of `RadioButton`) and connect them to the `@IBAction`. They worked like radio buttons

Comment: Thank you for your update. To better elaborate my inquiry, I'm not using storyboard to create the RadioButton. The storyboard has a MainView and add all the rest as subview the main is UIView while the buttons are RadioButtons based on UIButton. I hope this explain my question

Comment: Yes I'm creating RadioButtons by code `var frame = CGRect(x: j * (squareSize + spacing), y: j * n * (squareSize + spacing), width: 40, height: 40)
         
       var img = RadioButton(frame: frame) as? RadioButton
       
       let imgName = productOptionArray[j]["name"].stringValue`

Comment: @DavidBuik: I got the chance and looked into the library. I've updated my answer with the code using `RadioButton` from library.  It is working for me